# XPath function does not work in net framewok, but works with SQL query

Tags: c#, .net, t-sql, xpath

I have following XML and the query that works fine in SQL Server 2008, but fails when I select the same node with the functions `Concat` and `Substring` using `XmlDocument` object in C#.

What could be the issue?

```
declare @x xml='<asn>
      <asnH>
        <senderId>9053357373T</senderId>
        <pono>SCA0055792</pono>
        <dino>440229</dino>
        <shipmentWeight>1109</shipmentWeight>
        <loadingQty>190</loadingQty>di
        <zWeight>1109</zWeight>
      </asnH>
      <dd>
        <COMNO>010</COMNO>
        <T_x0024_ORNO>910055</T_x0024_ORNO>
        <T_x0024_CFRW>UP1</T_x0024_CFRW>
        <T_x0024_TRNO>abc-12345                     </T_x0024_TRNO>
        <T_x0024_DINO>440229</T_x0024_DINO>
        <T_x0024_ITEM>      817025-001</T_x0024_ITEM>
        <T_x0024_PONO>1</T_x0024_PONO>
        <T_x0024_DDAT>2017-08-14T00:00:00-04:00</T_x0024_DDAT>
        <T_x0024_DQUA>10</T_x0024_DQUA>
        <T_x0024_OQUA>10</T_x0024_OQUA>
        <T_x0024_WGHT>15</T_x0024_WGHT>
        <T_x0024_CUPS>ea </T_x0024_CUPS>
        <T_x0024_TRID>66085</T_x0024_TRID>
        <lWeight>150</lWeight>
      </dd>
    </asn>'

    select 
        t.c.query('concat(substring(asn[1]/asnH[1]/senderId[1],1,5),asn[1]/asnH[1]/dino[1])') 
    from
        @x.nodes('.')  t(c)
```

Comment: I think you should post the C# code that you are working with.

Comment: I don't think the XMLDocument object is the tool for the job. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx I substring and concate are string methods. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 ... but I'm not a .Net developer so I could be mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This give me result: 90533440229

```
string xml = @"<asn>
    <asnH>
    <senderId>9053357373T</senderId>
    <pono>SCA0055792</pono>
    <dino>440229</dino>
    <shipmentWeight>1109</shipmentWeight>
    <loadingQty>190</loadingQty>di
    <zWeight>1109</zWeight>
    </asnH>
    <dd>
    <COMNO>010</COMNO>
    <T_x0024_ORNO>910055</T_x0024_ORNO>
    <T_x0024_CFRW>UP1</T_x0024_CFRW>
    <T_x0024_TRNO>abc-12345                     </T_x0024_TRNO>
    <T_x0024_DINO>440229</T_x0024_DINO>
    <T_x0024_ITEM>      817025-001</T_x0024_ITEM>
    <T_x0024_PONO>1</T_x0024_PONO>
    <T_x0024_DDAT>2017-08-14T00:00:00-04:00</T_x0024_DDAT>
    <T_x0024_DQUA>10</T_x0024_DQUA>
    <T_x0024_OQUA>10</T_x0024_OQUA>
    <T_x0024_WGHT>15</T_x0024_WGHT>
    <T_x0024_CUPS>ea </T_x0024_CUPS>
    <T_x0024_TRID>66085</T_x0024_TRID>
    <lWeight>150</lWeight>
    </dd>
</asn>";

XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.InnerXml = xml;
XmlNode root = xmlDocument.DocumentElement;
string xpath = "concat(substring(asn[1]/asnH[1]/senderId[1],1,5),asn[1]/asnH[1]/dino[1])";
string s = root.ParentNode.CreateNavigator().Evaluate(xpath).ToString();
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Comment: Ruslan, your suggestion works.. but what I want is to use the native xpath functions (concat,substring in this case) evaluated as part of the xpath expression. Idea is to have all xpaths stored in the database and retrive values from the source xml document to another structure. The way you come up, will need re-parsing  the xpath string and needs to select each axis involved in the functions. Your suggestion lead me to understand that it is not possible to use the native functions with the xmldocument object. Therefore I think I am going to use XSLT to get this done. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @TonyP, sorry, I did not understand you correctly. I have edited my answer

Comment: Great , Exactly what I wanted, accepted as the Answer - Thanks

Comment: @TonyP, glad to help you